# Pinch zoom without UIScrollView based control

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

Is there an "accepted" way of performing (pinch) zoom on a view that is **not** based on UIScrollView?

Comment: I would /not/ suggest this: users expect a certain zooming "feeling", and replicating that /exactly/ is not simple.

Comment: look this sample on pinch zoom http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2011/03/pinch-zoom-using-uipinchgesturerecogniz.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [code sample by Erica Sadun](http://ipsw.info/svn/iphone-3.0-cookbook/C08-Gestures/14-Resize%20And%20Rotate/main.m) that does the math for treating touch events as scale/rotate/translate transforms that you can probably borrow from. Basically, it sounds like you want to apply a scaling affine transform. This code doesn't include the niceties of "bouncing" the view when you reach the edges of the content, so you'll have to do that yourself.

Full disclosure: I haven't done this in almost a year. It's likely that there are frameworks now that include much more straightforward support for this feature.

Comment: Your link requires basic auth. :-(

Comment: The code I was referring to has since been relocated to github: http://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/blob/master/C08-Gestures/14-Resize%20And%20Rotate/main.m Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in iPhone OS 3.2 (for the iPad) or iOS 4 for the iPhone 4, you can use the [UIPinchGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009283) class to detect pinch gestures.

Answer (score 0):

This code helps to zoom UIImageView without using UIScrollView.

```
-(void)HandlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"=======Scale Applied===========");
        if ([recognizer scale]<1.0f) {
            [recognizer setScale:1.0f];
        }
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale([recognizer scale],  [recognizer scale]);
        imgView.transform = transform;
    }
}
```